# Ionic 5 - Changing iOS default padding/margin value

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4, padding

I'm developing a mobile application using Ionic 4, and I want to change the default padding / margin of ionic elements which is **16px**, and I want to change it only in the IOS version. I'm actually not talking about the `ion-padding` / `ion-margin` CSS classes, because the default style on a ion-card for exemple came with a 16px padding by default, so is there any way to change this value ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
--padding-top: 10px;
--padding-start: 10px;
--padding-end: 10px;
--padding-bottom: 10px;
```